# Processing strategies

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I have three flows in my project

1) JMS(AtiveMQ queue) inbound connector --- message processors -- JMS(AtiveMQ queue) outbound connector

2) File inbound connector--- message processors --- JMS(AtiveMQ queue) outbound connector

3) File inbound connector--- message processors --- File inbound adapter connector

Which processing strategy will be best suitable for those? and how should we come to the conclusion ?

I went through mulesoft document on processing strategy which says decide it on exchange pattern and whether transport is transactional. But I did not get exactly how to decide here for best performance.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to use Mule 4 for best performance as Mule 4 includes a new execution engine that is based on a non-blocking runtime. This is a task-oriented execution model allowing you to take advantage of non-blocking IO calls and avoid performance problems due to incorrect processing strategy configurations.

Answer (score 0):

By default mule sets the processing strategy for each flow ,which is optimal for most cases. It applies synchronous processing strategy (process message in single thread) depending upon exchange pattern (request response) of your flow , or if your flow uses transaction. For other scenario it uses asynchronous processing strategy.

Your flow doesn't use any kind of request response pattern or transaction, hence by default asynchronous processing strategy would be applied to your flow. However you can customize the processing strategy and set different values for maxBufferSize, maxQueueSize, maxThreads, minThreads, etc. You can calculate the threads for your flow as shown in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/tuning-performance

```
<queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="asyn-processning" maxThreads="500"/>
```

There is other way to have custom processing strategy for your flow. I would advise you to go through the documents provided my mulesoft. They have explained it quite well. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/flow-processing-strategies#.